# Two spinners probability

Tags: probability

I have this interesting task, but I don't know how to solve it:

You may spin A twice, B twice, or A then B.
Which choice gives you the best chance of spinning a red
and a blue (purple)?

[image: Two spinners]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 : Spin A twice

$$P = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$$

Case 2 : Spin B twice

$$P = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Case 3 : Spin A once then B

$$P = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$

So, we see the probability is same in both case 2 and 3. Therefore, both cases are our best shot to get a purple